# Pointer is parially tampered, why is that and how to debug?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, gdb

I was assigned to develop a chat server which is written in C because the developer quit and I know a little of C.

I came across a bug these weeks, and was struggling with it for almost 2 weeks. I cannot even sleep now, please don't delete and Please help.

The chat server is using a event loop, every time a request come, it will create a `command` struct along with some other structs.

The `command` struct is

```
struct {
  struct {
    char *message;
    int length;
  } response;
  long count;
  int status;
} command;
```

Sometimes the `message` pointer is partially tampered, the normal pointer likes `0x00003fffxxxxxxxx` the binary is for example:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0110 1111 1111 1111 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  (pointerA)
```

and the corrupted pointer is always

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  (pointerB)
```

lower 33 bits of the pointer are always same, and higer 31 bits are always set to 0.

So if the `message` pointer is pointerB, and if I change the higher 31 bits to `0110 1111 1111 1111` so I get pointerB, if I print the content of `pointerB` in gdb, the content is correct.

It only happens under some load, and happens randomly. How can I debug this?

Comment: Couple hints: 1. Compile with all warnings on; 2. compile with different optimization switches; 3. look for casts in code (they are often wrong and silence the warnings)

Comment: Have you tried running your code with valgrind? That might show up where your code is corrupting the pointer

Comment: You don't show enough code to really help you. But it seems some code is overwriting the pointer. If you look at the data (variables) _before_ the struct, there is a good chance the code that manipulates that variable has the error.

Comment: @pmg tried, not work

Comment: @ChrisTurner if running it with valgrind, its too slow, the bug just does not happens

Comment: @PaulOgilvie it's a big project, impossible to show the code...

Comment: launch your program under the debugger, set a break pointer for when the pointer is `"0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1110 1010 0110 1011 0100 1000 0000 0000"` then look around

Comment: Is, maybe, this a typo??? You have `commond` in the code and `command` in the question text ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running on Linux, and apparently `x86_64`, your very first step should be to rebuild your binary with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (`gcc -fsanitize=address ...`).

Unlike (already suggested) Valgrind, Address Sanitizer catches overflows in global and stack variables (in addition to heap). It's also significantly faster.

> It only happens under some load, and happens randomly.

These in general suggest that you are accessing dangling memory. That is, you are using a pointer to `struct command` that has already been `free`d. Sometimes that memory is still sitting in the free pool, waiting to be allocated to something else, and other times that memory has already been allocated and overwritten.

If you can't find the bug with sanitizer, another approach is to find all places where `struct command` is being `free`d, and replace them with:

```
memset(p, 0xCD, sizeof(*p));
free(p);
```

That should make the bug significantly easier to reproduce and narrow down (if my guess about its nature is correct).

Comment: Thank you very much, let me try these methods